# Boost fusion using transform in for_each

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I'm trying to build a small C++ example using boost fusion. However, Visual Studio 2013 gives me build errors for the following piece of code. It should simply go over a associative struct and print all member names to the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/define_assoc_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/zip.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/transform.hpp>

namespace keys
{
     struct name
     {};
    struct id
     {};
}

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_ASSOC_STRUCT((), Student,
    (std::string, name, keys::name)
    (int, id, keys::id)
);

struct getnames
{
    template<typename Sig>
    struct result;

    template <typename S, typename T>
    struct result<getnames(S, T)>
    {
        typedef std::string type;
    };

    template<class Struct, class N>
    typename result<getnames(Struct, N)>::type operator() (const N& i) const
    {
        return boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name<Struct, i>::call();
    }
};

struct print
{
    template<typename Sig>
    struct result;

    template <typename T>
    struct result<print(T)>
    {
        typedef void type;
    };

    template<class S>
    void operator() (const S& i) const
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Student j = {"John", 42};
    auto names = boost::fusion::transform(j, getnames());
    boost::fusion::for_each(names, print());
    return 0;
}
```

This is my error:
`boost/fusion/view/transform_view/detail/deref_impl.hpp(38): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::apply<boost::fusion::detail::apply_transform_result<getnames>,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na,boost::mpl::na>'`
and four more errors which are coming up because of the first one.

To be honest, I am not an expert in the usage of boost fusion so maybe I simply missed something important here and someone else can help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

1) In the Functor `getnames`, the signature of the `result` type and the signature of `operator()` are inconsistent (one takes one argument, the other takes two).

2) in the `operator()(const N& i)`, `i` is a runtime variable. It cannot appear as a template parameter in the expression `boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name<Struct, i>`.

I am not sure how to help without knowing what you want to do with `getnames`. Try to get to a consistent code first.

Comment: If `N` is an `integral_constant` `i` can [be used as a template parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835689/accessing-boost-fusion-map-field-name/17842958#17842958) with clang and g++.  I suspect the asker tried to copy code from somewhere and forgot an important part.

Comment: I think, `i` cannot appear as a temperature parameter inside the body of the function. It is not a type, it is a variable, even if it an integer it is not a constexpr.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, so I don't know whether it's a bug in both [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ad9a8a84483d66f) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4cc487d70b29afe). In [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/LPRN14803) it does not work.

Comment: @cv_and_he, me neither. and you are correct, it works in `g++` and `clang` (as taken from your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835689/accessing-boost-fusion-map-field-name/17842958#17842958). **I wonder what kind of magic is working on there! It is very strange to me why it works** and if it has any non-trivial application. (BTW, OP code looks very similar to yours in the linked answer)

Comment: I agree that some parts in my code are wrong. This is mainly because I didn't see or use some of the syntax in this way before (like e.g. the mentioned `struct result<getnames(S, T)>` which should have one argument instead of two).  I will clean this up tomrrow.  However, about 2): Boost tests for fusion have some examples where they often declare `template<typename T> void operator()(T& t)` this or in a similar way. Thanks for the answers so far!