# Boost Fusion: convert adapted struct type to text

Tags: c++, introspection, boost-fusion

Given a struct like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Foo, x, y, z);
```

I want to generate a string like this:

```
"{ int x; int y; double z; }"
```

I have seen how to [print the *values*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17660354/4323) of a Fusion adapted struct, but here I need to print the types and names only.

How can I do this mostly simply?  I'm not married to Boost.Fusion if there's a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can get something similar to what you want by making some slight modifications on the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842958/2417774). You can easily get the member name using `boost::fusion::extension::struct_member_name` but, as far as I know, you can't directly get the member type name. You can get the member type using `boost::fusion::result_of::value_at` (amongst other options) and I've chosen to use Boost.TypeIndex to get its name (in varying degrees of prettiness, depending on the compiler and the types in question). All of this is assuming that you actually need the Fusion adaptation, if you don't you can probably get a simpler approach that does only what you need.

**Full Code**
[Running on WandBox (gcc)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/garJmgbRY9Do9I9j)
[Running on rextester (vc)](http://rextester.com/PQL69470)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/zip.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>

#include <boost/type_index.hpp>


namespace fusion=boost::fusion;
namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Foo, x, y, z);

struct Bar
{
    std::pair<int,int> p;
    std::string s;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Bar, p, s);

template <typename Sequence>
struct Struct_member_printer
{
    Struct_member_printer(const Sequence& seq):seq_(seq){}
    const Sequence& seq_;
    template <typename Index>
    void operator() (Index) const
    {

        std::string member_type = boost::typeindex::type_id<typename fusion::result_of::value_at<Sequence,Index>::type >().pretty_name() ;
        std::string member_name = fusion::extension::struct_member_name<Sequence,Index::value>::call();

        std::cout << member_type << " " << member_name << "; ";
    }
};
template<typename Sequence>
void print_struct(Sequence const& v)
{
    typedef mpl::range_c<unsigned, 0, fusion::result_of::size<Sequence>::value > Indices; 
    std::cout << "{ ";
    fusion::for_each(Indices(), Struct_member_printer<Sequence>(v));
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    print_struct(foo);

    Bar bar;
    print_struct(bar);
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you.  What did you mean by "If you don't need the Fusion adaptation you can probably get a simpler approach"?  You mean by defining my own macro without using Fusion at all?

Comment: From your question I don't know your actual use case, I can imagine a case where you already are using the adapted struct and want to additionally print its representation, in which case this is a good solution; but I could also see a case where you are just using Fusion because of its "reflection" / "introspection"  capabilities without using anything else, in that case the adaptation is doing a lot more work than what you actually need.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution which is compiler dependent (tested on clang / gcc / MSVC) and only works if you have c++14 (should work with c++11 after slight modifications). It does what you want but there may be simpler solutions...

First part is a bit of compiler dependent code to **demangle names** return by `std::type_info::name`:

```
#include <string>

#if defined __GNUC__

#include <cxxabi.h>

std::string demangle (const char *name) {
    int status = 0;
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(name, 0, 0, &status);
}

#elif defined _WIN32 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <DbgHelp.h>

std::string demangle (const char *name) {
    char buffer[1024];
    UnDecorateSymbolName(name, buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer), 0);
    return buffer;
}

#endif
```

Then the "generic" part is quite short:

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>


template <typename Tuple, size_t ...Idx>
std::string to_string (std::string vars, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    std::array<const char *, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value> tnames{
        typeid(typename std::tuple_element<Idx, Tuple>::type).name()...};
    std::stringstream res;
    res << "{ ";
    for (auto s: tnames) {
        size_t end = vars.find(',');
        res << demangle(s) << ' ' << vars.substr(0, end) << "; ";
        vars = vars.substr(end + 2);
    }
    res << '}';
    return res.str();
}

#define CREATE(S, ...) struct: S { \
    using Tuple = decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__)); \
    std::string operator()() { \
        return to_string<Tuple>(#__VA_ARGS__, \
            std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>{}); \
    }; \
}
```

The idea is to create a class `L` that inherits from the specified class (e.g. `Foo`) and use the `__VA_ARGS__` macro to expands the attribute names into `std::make_tuple` to obtain their types.

The `to_string` retrieves the `std::type_info::name` of each elements from a `tuple` and combines it with the attribute names (e.g. `"x, y, z"`).

The `CREATE` macro returns a lambda that you can use as follow:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
};

CREATE(Foo, x, y, z) foo_xyz;

#include <iostream>

int main () {
   std::cout << foo_xyz() << std::endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
{ int x; int y; double z; }
```

**Note:** Since demangling is compiler dependent, you may not get exactly the same output with all compilers... For instance if you have a `std::array<int, 10>`:

```
gcc: std::array<int, 10ul>
clang: std::__1::array<int, 10ul>
msvc: class std::array<int,10>
```

**Note:** The usage is "complicated" to support MSVC: Initially I used a lambda inside `CREATE` so that you could do `CREATE(Foo, x, y, z)()` without having to bother creating a variable (I do not know how to generate correct name - see initial version of this answer), but MSVC do not like `decltype(std::make_tuple(x, y, z))` inside the lambda... (probably a bug).