# decltype using parent's member not working inside lambda on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

The following code compiles on GCC, Clang and MSVC:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
};

struct Bar: Foo {
    decltype(x) z;
};
```

But this one do not compile with MSVC:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
};

auto m = [] () {
    struct Bar: Foo {
        decltype(x) z;
    };
};
```

The error is:

> error C4573: the usage of 'Foo::x' requires the compiler to capture 'this' but the current default capture mode does not allow it

Which seems so wrong to me... So I was wondering if this was a MSVC bug or if this was an extension of gcc/clang?

In all cases, is there another way to do what I want without having to prefix `x` (`decltype(Foo::x)`) inside `Bar`?

---

**Note:** The original problem arise when writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39034543/2666289), where I basically wanted to do the following to avoid having to generate names in macro:

```
auto something = [] () {
    struct: Foo {
        decltype(x) z;
        auto operator()() { return z; }
    } foo;
    return foo.operator();
}();
```

Currently I am using a struct so I have to do something like:

```
MACRO(Foo, x) my_var;
// or... MACRO(my_var, Foo, x);
auto value = my_var();
```

But I would like:

```
auto value = MACRO(Foo, x);
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? VS2015(v140) compiles the second code with lambda with no problems.

Comment: @DeanSeo It is VC++ 19.00.23506, the version on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/EECOI71008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is a compiler bug.

> It is VC++ 19.00.23506, the version on rextester.com

The latest VC++ compiler, the version of which is `19.00.24213`, has fixed that issue.

Apparently using `decltype` inside lambda in VC++ had brought [some issues detecting type from out of scope](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1883258).

Telling the compiler explicitly `Foo::x` can be a work around, as you have already figured it out.